# Select Top item from group

Tags: oracle, group-by, top

I have a simple table

| ID | Product | Version | Price | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pizza | 1 | 10.00 | It is good |
| 2 | Pizza | 2 | 11.00 | The best yet |
| 3 | Soda | 1 | 3:00 |  |
| 4 | Hot dog | 1 | 8.00 | 20% meat |
| 5 | Soda | 2 | 3.00 | Rebranded |

I want to get out the ID of the latest version of the product. Product is a text value (I have no control on this)

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

I will then be using this in an IN clause hence just wanting the ID

Normally I would look to use a `group by product`, then use `max(version)`, however, I am not sure how to get the ID as it is not a grouped field.

I can't guarantee that the highest version will also have the highest ID (I do not control the DB)

Comment: I can't guarantee that the highest version will also have the highest ID (I do not control the DB)

Comment: as you ave no other column for the table to sort by, the id is the only possibility to select the "latest" if you don't priovide a time column

Comment: I will then use the id column then and make that assumption

Answer (score 0):

You can work along

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Version DESC) AS rn
  FROM Product
  )
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

It uses the window function `ROW_NUMBER()` in the inner query to rank the the product versions. The outer query preserves just the top most version for each product.

Instead of selecting `WHERE ... IN` you could `JOIN` as well.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/178030/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.